# Why can't execute "npm start" or even other npm commands?

Tags: node.js, npm

What could the problem be? I get this error whenever i run "npm start" or even basic commands like "npm install." I am trying to figure out why it can't run.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-  cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.32
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info prestart nodetest1@0.0.0
7 info start nodetest1@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info nodetest1@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
10 error nodetest1@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
10 error spawn ENOENT
11 error Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.0 start script.
11 error This is most likely a problem with the nodetest1 package,
11 error not with npm itself.
11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11 error     node ./bin/www
11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls nodetest1
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error cwd C:\Users\Kijo\nodetest1
15 error node -v v0.10.32
16 error npm -v 1.4.28
17 error syscall spawn
18 error code ELIFECYCLE
19 error errno ENOENT
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

@nox3011
Here is a printout of my directory, if it can help.[image: Project Directory.]

Comment: Without seeing your directory structure, it will be difficult for anyone to help you answer this. You clearly have a path issue in your current project or you have not setup "npm start" in your package.json properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ENOENT error which means it was not able to locate some required file or directory. Mostly with ./bin/www
Try running npm start by changing directory to C:\Program Files\node